# Android Studio Calendar Picker

Tags: android, datepicker

Im trying to get the user to select a date when the click on a button and it shows 3 scroll wheels to choose day, month and year it will then set whatever the user selected to the text view, at the moment when i click the button nothing is happening just empty clicks any help would be appreciated. I will insert the code below. I am recieving an error on this line of code.

```
fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "date");
```

Datepicker Code

```
public void datePicker(View view) {
        DatePickerFragment fragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "date");
    }

    public void setDate(final Calendar calendar) {
        final DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateSet)).setText(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, dayOfMonth);
        setDate(cal);
    }

    public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                    (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener)
                            getActivity(), year, month, day);
        }


        public void show(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager, String date) {
        }
    }

}
```

Button and TextView Code:

```
<TextView
        android:text=""
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dateSet"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Category"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Pick Date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/dateSet"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/incomeDate"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/incomeDate"
        android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
        android:onClick="datePicker"
        android:id="@+id/picDate" />
```

error:

```
Error:(135, 17) error: no suitable method found for show(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager,String)
method DialogFragment.show(android.app.FragmentManager,String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager cannot be converted to android.app.FragmentManager)
method DialogFragment.show(FragmentTransaction,String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager cannot be converted to FragmentTransaction)
```

Comment: Remember that the computer does exactly what you tell it and nothing more. In this case, `show()` does nothing.

Comment: I forgot to remove that it was giving me an error tilli inserted that ill redo the question sorry

Comment: I suggest you learn how to display a fragment dynamically.

Comment: i updated the question with the error

Comment: You are mixing the support library with the native API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is a little confusing, especially if you only pay attention to the class names and ignore their packages. The problem is that the Support Library uses identical class names as the native API. To fix the problem, double check the imports for classes which should use the support library. For example

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment
```

Most likely you have

```
import android.app.DialogFragment
```

which is a class from the Native API. Even though these two classes have the same name, they are two different types because they are in different packages.

Comment: so i should check to see does it use that import or a different import?

Comment: @chris123 Made a small edit to clarify the different imports.